# Send mail to all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

```
    class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'nixers@fixrnix.in'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://www.fixrnix.in'
    mail(to: @user.email , subject: 'Welcome to FixNix Audit Management')
  end
end
```

How can i send email to all users instead of single user  **mail(to: `@user.email` , subject: 'Welcome to FixNix Audit Management')**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass array of addresses as well:

```
def welcome_email(users)
  @url  = 'http://www.fixrnix.in'
  mail(to: users.pluck[:email] , subject: 'Welcome to FixNix Audit Management')
end
```

However, if your email body depends on the user or you don't want mailed users to see other users's addresses you can't do this. You need to create a new message for each user and send it separately.

```
users.each do |user|
  YourMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver
end
```

Comment: @BroiState, second approach is better and reasonable too. And it would be better for OP to use Delayed Job to deliver emails in bulk. +1 to you.

Comment: Yes, definitely better to send the email X times than send one email to X users.  Theoretically you could use bcc for the latter but you're more likely to trigger spam filters.  Plus bcc emails are very unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in your mailer

```
emails = users.collect(&:email).join(", ")
mail(to: emails, subject: 'Welcome to FixNix Audit Management')
```

Hope this helps!